# Chrome extension: XHR request to website, get html content by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am creating a chrome extension that will go to a specified website, and get parts of the site's HTML from the source code. 
I want to get the html content contained within a div with class name 'span1 rating-num-span'.

I tried using .getElementsByClassName but it returned undefined, however when I use .getElementsByTagName on ('h2') it worked.

Here is the javascript function to make the request from my main.js

```
function getFlowSite(){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (request.readyState == 4){
        if (request.status == 200){
            var temp = document.createElement('div');
            temp.innerHTML = request.responseText;

            alert(temp.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerText);
            alert(temp.getElementsByClassName('span1 rating-num-span')[0].innerText);


        }
        else{
            console.log("Messed up!!!");
        }
    }
};
request.open("GET", "http://uwflow.com/course/" + courseName, true);
request.send(null);
}
```

stumped... 
Thanks for reading!

--------------------Update------------------------

Turns out the class isn't present initially on the page, and is loaded in dynamically with a script. How can I get the source code of the page after everything is loaded in?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` expects a **single** class name. you could use `temp.querySelector('.span1.rating-num-span')` instead - or `temp.querySelectorAll('.span1.rating-num-span')[0]`

Comment: @Jaromanda using the querySelector returns null, while querySelectorAll returns undefined when i alert() them

Comment: request.responseText grabs html from the site shown here, with the source code: "http://i.imgur.com/hqlaqfb.png?1"

Comment: Maybe that site adds this element dynamically with a script so it simply is not present initially on the page. You can check this by examining the first server response from the site when loading it with devtools Network panel open. Or use `wget http://uwflow.com/course/.............................` to fetch the initial response.

Comment: @wOxxOm You're right, the class doesn't exist when it is initially loaded. Do you know how I can get the page data after everything is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That element is added by the page script dynamically.

It's not present initially on the page. You can check this by examining the first server response from the site when loading it with devtools Network panel open. Or, if you use the great uBlock (origin) extension, simply disable all javascript on the site temporarily and reload the page.

You have two options:

1. **find out how that webpage's code fetches the data** from the server/elsewhere and do it yourself, there's usually some kind of JSON API. For example in this case there's a huge config object right in the page:

   ```
   <script>
     window.pageData.courseObj = {"ratings": [{"count": 375, "rating": .............
   ```

   Simply use XMLHttpRequest with `.responseType = "document"` mode and get that element, then use `JSON.parse` on it.

   Or, actually, in this case a simple regexp + JSON.parse will do:

   ```
   var match = request.responseText
                      .match(/window\.pageData\.courseObj\s*=\s*(\{.+?\});\s*[\r\n]/);
   var config = JSON.parse(match[1]);
   config.ratings.forEach(function(r) { console.log(r) });
   ```

   > Object {count: 375, rating: 0.6986666666666667, name: "usefulness"}
   >   Object {count: 494, rating: 0.7449392712550608, name: "easiness"}
   >   Object {count: 555, rating: 0.5621621621621622, name: "interest"}

   The above code wasn't tested live and doesn't contain any error checks which must be implemented in the real code.
2. **load the page as a normal browser tab without activating it, inject a content script**, wait for the element to appear, extract the data, close the tab.

   *manifest.json:*

   `"permissions": ["http://uwflow.com/*"]` - permissions for executeScript on non-active tab

   *popup.js:*

   ```
   var globalTabId = 0;

   function openTab(url) {
       chrome.tabs.create({url: url, active: false}, function(tab) {
           globalTabId = tab.id;
           chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "getData.js", runAt: "document_end"});
       });
   }

   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, response) {
       if (msg.action == "data" && sender.tab && sender.tab.id == globalTabId) {
           chrome.tabs.remove(globalTabId);
           processData(msg.data);
       }
   });
   ```

   *getData.js*, this is a content script but it doesn't need to be declared in manifest.json.

   ```
   var interval = setInterval(function() {
       var ratings = document.querySelector(".span1.rating-num-span");
       if (!ratings) {
           return;
       }
       clearInterval(interval);
       chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "data", data: {ratings: ratings.textContent}});
   }, 100);
   ```